# Spring context initialization with runtime values

Tags: java, spring, swing

I'm trying to integrate Spring in a standalone Swing application.
The Swing application asks for login details at start-up, which should then be used to create a singleton `DataSource` Bean.

However I can't come up with a way to pass those login info (as Java object) to the Spring `ApplicationContext` during initialization (which would then be passed down to the `@Bean` producer method).

Any ideas?

---

Possible solution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoSwingApplication {
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    ...

    final var loginInfo = buildLoginInfo();

    try (final var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext()) {
      context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("loginInfo", loginInfo);
      context.register(DemoSwingApplication.class);
      context.refresh();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways in which you can do this,

**Using BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor** - Create a bean which will implement `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` and then store the `BeanDefinitionRegistry` instance and dynamically register your bean.

```
@Component
public class DbConfigurer implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware {

    private BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry beanDefinitionRegistry) throws BeansException {
        this.beanDefinitionRegistry = beanDefinitionRegistry;
    }

    public void registerDataSourceBean() {
        beanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition("dataSource", new RootBeanDefinition(DataSource.class,
                BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON, yourDataSourceBeanSupplier));
    }
}
```

**Using BeanFactoryAware** - This is similar to implementation that you provided but by implementing `BeanFactoryAware` interface but downside of this is to check for `BeanFactory` instance -

```
@Component
public class DbConfigurer implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware {

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory defaultListableBeanFactory = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory; // Need to cast
    }
}
```

And then in your `UI` component, inject this `And` and register bean when config properties are available -

```
@Component
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private final DbConfigurer dbConfigurer;

    // register bean once user provides config properties
}
```

and start your application using headless mode disabled -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DesktopApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DesktopApplication.class).headless(false).run(args);
    }

}
```